# How to build custom assertions in C#/VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I ran into a bug in some code that extracts metadata from some text and puts it into a dictionary.

My test was failing when I compared two dictionary objects because the keys were in different order. I don't really care what order the keys are in.

I'd like to have an assert method available like :

```
Assert.AreEquivalent(propsExpected,propsActual)
```

That would evaluate like:

```
Assert.AreEqual(propsExpected.Count, propsActual.Count);
foreach (var key in propsExpected.Keys)
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(props[key]);
    Assert.AreEqual(propsExpected[key], props[key]);
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The trick here is to use a new feature of .Net 3.5 called [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

For example to get the Assert class to support the AreEquivalent method using the code you supplied above, you would do something like this:

```
public static class MyAssertExtensions
{
    public static void AreEquivalent(this Assert ast, 
        Dictionary<string, int> propsExpected, 
        Dictionary<string, int> propsActual)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(propsExpected.Count, propsActual.Count);
        foreach (var key in propsExpected.Keys)
        {
            Assert.IsNotNull(props[key]);
            Assert.AreEqual(propsExpected[key], props[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can actually call the assertion like this:

```
Assert.AreEquivalent(propsExpected,propsActual);
```

Comment: The problem here is that if the elements in the two dictionaries don't have the same order, the assertion will fail even if the elements are equals

Comment: @Marwan: no, it only asserts that the collections are the same size and that, for every key in collection 1, the same key also exists in collection 2 with the same value.  Order is never an issue.

Comment: To call this you need 'Assert.That.AreEquivalent()'

Comment: You can't create extension methods for Assert because it is a static class, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020503/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-custom-extension-methods-for-vs-ut-assert-class

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, take a look at 
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.CollectionAssert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert_members%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use LINQ,

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary d1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    Dictionary d2 = new Dictionary<int, string>();  

    d1.Add(1, "1");
    d1.Add(2, "2");  
    d1.Add(3, "3");  

    d2.Add(2, "2");  
    d2.Add(1, "1");  
    d2.Add(3, "3");  

    Console.WriteLine(d1.Keys.Except(d2.Keys).ToArray().Length);  
}
```

This prints 0 to the console. Except tries to find the difference between two lists in the above example.

You can compare this with 0 to find if there is any difference.

EDIT: You could add the check for comparing the length of 2 dictionaries before doing this.
i.e. You can use Except, ***only*** if the length differs.

Answer (score 1):

With NUnit, you can compare two collections using the Is.EquivalentTo() constraint.  This constraint will evaluate the collection and check whether the collection has the same elements, but it doesn't care about the order.

[Documentation for CollectionEquivalentConstraint](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.5)
If you don't use NUnit, then maybe something similar exists in the testing framework you're using?

Answer (score 1):

As @Sprintstar pointed out in the comments for the @Michael La Voie 's answer, the Assert class can't be extended because of it's static nature, the way I tackle this problem usually is by creating a test repository which contains my customized methods with multiple asserts and other validations taking place in the same method. For ex-

```
public static class MyTestRepository
{   
    public static void ArePropsEquivalent(
        Dictionary<string, int> propsExpected, 
        Dictionary<string, int> propsActual)
    {
        //Multiple Asserts and validation logic
        //required for Equivalence goes here
    }

    public static void ArePropsSimilar(
        Dictionary<string, int> propsExpected, 
        Dictionary<string, int> propsActual)
    {
        //Multiple Asserts and validation logic 
        //required for similarity goes here
    }
}
```

I then call these methods from the unit test methods.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMthod1()
{
    //Props declaration goes here
    MyTestRepository.ArePropsEquivalent(propsExpected, propsActual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMthod2()
{
    //Props declaration goes here
    MyTestRepository.ArePropsSimilar(propsExpected, propsActual);
}
```

This way I am able to write less and do more in the actual unit test case methods and keep it modular (in case of different models).

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible (probably added by MS since the question was originally answered) - the extension will work if you use the `That` singleton.

In which case the extension could be called as:

```
Assert.That.AreEquivalent(propsExpected,propsActual);
```

Answer (score 0):

From these posts it looks like MbUnit already supports this with AreElementsEqualIgnoringOrder.

http://japikse.blogspot.com/2008/12/my-favorite-mbunit-assertions.html

http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/2008/10/announcing-gallio-and-mbunit-v304.html