# What is the best way to create custom extension methods for VS UT Assert class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, mstest

I would like to know what is the best way to write custom extensions methods for Microsoft Visual Studio Unit Testing Assert class.

Comment: I wrote my own extendible wrapper that sites on top of Assert. The source code can be found here: https://github.com/bbraithwaite/MSTestExtensions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are referring to this [Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class, then you cannot add extension methods. Extension methods can only be applied to object instances. Since this class is static, it can never be instantiated.

You could add your own custom Assert type class like so though:

```
public static class MyAssert {
    public static void AreEqual(object expected, object actual) {
        // TODO: throw if not equal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can create extension methods for this [Assert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert?view=mstest-net-1.2.0) class.

The version of class *Assert* is now as:

```
public sealed class Assert
{
    private static Assert that;

    public static Assert That
    {
        get
        {
            if (Assert.that == null)
                Assert.that = new Assert();
            return Assert.that;
        }
    }
}
```

Which means now you can create extension methods for the *Assert* class.

For example you can have the extension method:

```
public static class AssertExtensions
{
    public static void IsDateToday(this Assert assert, DateTime today)
    {
        if (today.Date != DateTime.Now.Date)
        {
            throw new AssertFailedException("Kaboom! Assert failed bro..");
        }
    }
}
```

And then on unit tests you can make:

```
Assert.That.IsDateToday(someDateTime);
```